# event.preventDefault(); not working with .on in jQuery

Tags: jquery

As of jQuery 1.7 `.live` has been deprecated and replaced with `.on`. However, I am having difficulty getting jQuery `.on` to work with `event.preventDefault();`. In the below example, clicking the anchor tag takes me to the linked page instead of preventing the default browser action of following the link.

```
jQuery('.link-container a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
//do something
});
```

However, the same code with `.live` works without any hiccups.

```
jQuery('.link-container a').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
//do something
});
```

I am using jQuery version 1.7.1 that ships with Wordpress 3.3.1 currently. What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not binding it correctly. The `.on()`-method works like a `.delegate()` when doing what you want to do. Here's an example of proper usage:

```
$('.link-container').on('click', 'a', function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

This is assuming that .link-container is there on page load, and isn't dynamically loaded. You need to bind the delegate method to the closest ancestor that's statically there, and in the second argument, in this case `'a'`, specify what items the delegate method applies to.

Just using `$('selector').on('click', function() { })` gives exactly the same result as using `$('selector').click(function(){ })`

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gTZXp/

Comment: Thx for a clear explanation. Your example works. However, the only parent container that is available during page load is atleast 3 levels above and there are other anchor tags in this nested structure. The example of yours starts affecting other anchor tags, which I do not intend to. What should be done to avoid the same?

Comment: Got this done by specifying a separate class for the anchor tags.

Comment: That's one solution, the other is to continue the selector in the second argument, i.e. instead of using `$('#container').on('click', 'a')`, you could use a more specific selector, like `$('#container').on('click', '.someContainer .link-container a')`. But using a class works just dandy :)

Comment: Thx for the info. Would be helpful in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

If your `a` elements are being added dynamically you need to use `on()` with a filter (as `delegate()` used to be), like this:

```
jQuery('.link-container').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //do something
});
```

This makes the assumption that `.link-container` is not dynamic, and is available to the DOM on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){    
     j('.link-container').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     });     
});
```